# Flutter : the for loop for validation just read the first index not all of the indexs

Tags: flutter, dart

I have some multi fields that I would like to send in the multi part method, and I have set a validation condition on them using the for loop for it , but in my case the validation work just on the first index and didn't work on the others .

Edit :

Now ,after remove return statement it entered to else condition and not stopped after the first one

this is my current code which i using :

```
onPressed: () {
              for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                 if (_frontImagesFiles[i] == null ||
                    _backImagesFiles[i] == null ||
                    _controllerListPhones[i].text.isEmpty ||
                    _controllerListNames[i].text.isEmpty) {
                  showAlert(i);
                } else if (_controllerListPhones[i].value.text.length != 11) {
                  phone(i);
                } else {
                  upload(_frontImagesFiles, _backImagesFiles);
                }
              }
            },
```

Comment: The `return` statement may impact your iteration

Comment: Where are you calling this onPressed method?

Comment: @dm_tr i remove the return before but the same problem still

Comment: @JoeMuller in the bottomSheet i using button in it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use it without 'return'
In your case, when using 'return', the for loop exits

```dart
    onPressed: () {
                  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                     if (_frontImagesFiles[i] == null ||
                        _backImagesFiles[i] == null ||
                        _controllerListPhones[i].text.isEmpty ||
                        _controllerListNames[i].text.isEmpty) {
                      showAlert(i);
                    } else if (_controllerListPhones[i].value.text.length != 11) {
                      phone(i);               
                    } else {
                      upload(_frontImagesFiles, _backImagesFiles);
                    }
                  }
                },
```

Comment: OP already said that removing `return` statement gives the save effect

Comment: that's right but after the dialog of the validation appear it is continue the other conditions and entered to upload in else and i won't that

Comment: please check my above comment @dm_tr